# Calculate size of custom collectionView cell at run time with typing text

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I have made custom cell and reusable with **typingIndicator** data source method of MessageKit. I want to calculate size of the custom cell and update the height with the actual text of typed by another user. Can you help me with the below UI?[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've completed 70%, but there is not any update method for real-time typed text with typing, so I am not able to calculate the size of cell and text. There is only one method for typing indicator view hide and show. But i want to show always and udpate everything.

Comment: Why is it a collectionViewCell and not `UITableViewCell`?